# Удалить свойство объекта redux react

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs, объекты, redux

Суть такова, я использую react-redux и стороннюю библиотеку normalizr, 
таким образом я имею некоторый объект объектов который выглядит примерно следующий образом

```js
{
bk_FeuYzQsBuV8O3tgN--: {id: "bk_FeuYzQsBuV8O3tgN--", check: false, title: "4"}
kjbzERM6wESqX8__ddiul: {id: "kjbzERM6wESqX8__ddiul", check: false, title: "2"}
mwVrYsG00ORmOsZaVP4mk: {id: "mwVrYsG00ORmOsZaVP4mk", check: false, title: "3"}
zwWvY0uV3YtKf3KsR9Pjf: {id: "zwWvY0uV3YtKf3KsR9Pjf", check: false, title: "1"}
}
```

т.е. есть объект в нем лежат ключи и этим ключам соответствуют какие-то объекты,
и также имею массив ключей

```js
[zwWvY0uV3YtKf3KsR9Pjf", "kjbzERM6wESqX8__ddiul", "mwVrYsG00ORmOsZaVP4mk", "bk_FeuYzQsBuV8O3tgN--"]
```

моя задача состоит в том, что я хочу удалить определенную задачу из списка, например, зная ID, я передаю в action.payload id задачи которую мне нужно удалить и делаю это так

```js
  case REMOVE_TASK:
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: {
          ...state.tasks,
          entities: delete [action.payload[0]]
        }
      };
```

Но после этого действия получаю ошибку
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
собственно, я понимаю почему она происходит, потому что вероятно из объекта свойство удалилось неправильно, что скорей всего, но также массив ID остался тем же, собственно сам вопрос, как правильно удалить в таком случае определенную задачу из объекта и нужно ли будет потом при этом фильтровать массив с ID?

Comment: В редюсере state - это что? И откуда взялась такая структура tasks:{entities:}. А вообще Cannot read property 'id' of undefined - это выдает, когда пытаешь работать с несуществующими данными. action.payload[0] - явно такого нет. ЧТо вы туда передаете? Массив? В консоль его вывидите и посмотрите есть ли там что-то.

Comment: После выполнения `entities: delete [action.payload[0]]` у вас в entities будет лежать `true\false`. Оператор `delete` возвращает булевское значение.